# SPF google mail + MY IP

Tags: gmail, spf

So this TEXT record response hardfail

XX.XX.XX.XX => my mail server

```
v=spf1 ip4:XX.XX.XX.XX include:aspmx.googlemail.com ~all
```

Question is how to create valid SPF record for sending e-mail

- for my server IP
- and using google mail servers, i thin problem is witch -all ~all

Comment: FWIW, [Google suggest](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=178723) that you should `include:_spf.google.com`

Comment: The ending `~all` is used while you are testing your SPF records but don't want them to actually *do* anything yet.  The ending `-all` is for once they are correct and you want people to reject email that claims to be from you but isn't.

Answer (score 3):

I used to work for a company that had Google as their main email provider and this is an example of the SPF record.

```
v=spf1 a mx ip4:X.X.X.X ip4:Y.Y.Y.Y include:_spf.google.com include:blackberryservers.domain.com -all
```

So we could definite additional static IPs that we want to relay through us as well as the Google servers. We also did a lot of Blackberry email so we had a dig command set up to pull the SPF servers for the Blackberry servers. From here we put them in a separate spf record and then included it on the main SPF record. If you don't trust the _spf.google.com you can create a similar dig script to show all of the IPs and then cron it and diff the results on an hourly or daily basis.

Below is a small part of that code. I haven't used this in a while but I believe the output should still be the same.

```
PREVIOUS=/home/user/google_ips
NEW=`dig txt _spf.google.com | grep _spf | grep -ve ";" | awk -F\" '{print $2}' | tr ' ' '\n' | sort`
if [ "$PREVIOUS" != "$NEW" ]; then
echo $NEW | nail -r your@email.com
fi
```

Comment: Google search S*CK, 3 hours and only wrong information  --  THX , that solve my problem

Comment: OK now its working i had receive 4 new email that should be delivery day ego :)

Comment: Very glad to hear it!